# Почему не работает запрос

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Есть такой запрос. Интересно почему он не работает.

> $cikl1 = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`,
>   `photo`, `uidvk` FROM `users` WHERE `rotspisok` = 1; UPDATE `users`
>   SET `rot` = `rot` + 1 WHERE `uidvk` = 288988637");

Comment: все эти библиотеки  php работы с mysql выполняют только один запрос. сделайте два обращения, заработает

Comment: то есть в хвост запроса даже инъекцию не встроить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работайте через PDO, mysqli это уже прошлый век, вродебы даже не поддерживается уже. И да , 1 выражение = 1 запрос.

$sql_select = "SELECT first_name, last_name,  photo, uidvk FROM users WHERE rotspisok = 1";
$sql_update = "UPDATE users SET rot = rot + 1 WHERE uidvk = 288988637";

mysqli_query($CONNECT, $sql_select );

mysqli_query($CONNECT, $sql_update );

Comment: mysqli это уже прошлый век - не соглашусь, на вкус и цвет. Осторожнее с такими высказываниями!

Comment: рекомендую использовать PDO

Comment: Интересно, кто плюсует эту дремучую ерунду про прошлый век?

Comment: @JuraZubach PHP API предоставляет на выбор три набора инструментов для подключения к серверу баз данных: расширение PHP MySQL, расширение PHP mysqli, объекты данных PHP PDO - и каждый из них имеет свои достоинства и недостаткию. Так например PDO поддерживает не весь функционал множественных запросов MySQL 4.1+ в отличие от mysqli, а mysqli не поддерживает подготавливаемые запросы на стороне клиента в отличие от PDO